# accessing variables from config file in CI_Lang subclass

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a file `my_config.php` at location `application->config` and made its entry in `autoload.php` like
`$autoload['config'] = array('my_config');`
I need to access an item `languages` defined inside `my_config.php` in a file `MY_Lang.php` that extends `CI_Lang.php`. My code is as follows

```
$languages = $this->config->item('languages', 'my_config');
```

But this throws following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in /var/www/html/my_project/application/core/MY_Lang.php on line 47
```

I can access like this in my `controller` file but not in `MY_Lang.php` file

Comment: Do you have an item `languages` in your `my_config` file ?

Comment: @OwaisAslam Yes I do have `languages` item in `my_config` file. I can access that in my `controller` too.